# Position of more with a verb

Tags: verbs, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement

I want to say that I did something in a certain way and when I tried to do that with another method it didn't work.  I wrote:

> So I tried the same in this other method and it didn't work more than in my first attempt.

Is the sentence correct? Is the position of 'more' correct?

Comment: Normally (and idiomatically), one would say *it worked less* to avoid confusion between *(didn't work) more* and *didn't (work more)*.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use *more*. *better* or *worse* would be better, since you are referring to results, not quantity.

Also *as well as* can be used.

You could say:

> I tried juggling four eggs standing on both feet. Then I tried the same standing on one foot.

Then you could say:

> I tried the same in this other method and it didn't work **any better than** my first attempt.
>   I tried the same in this other method and it didn't work **as well as** my first attempt.